# Is there any opensource software like cpanel?

Tags: linux, cpanel

Have to know this thing that it exist or not.

Comment: You will reach more people who *might be able to answer* if you said what cpanel does, or at least provided a link, no?

Answer (score 7):

[Comparison of web hosting control panels.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_hosting_control_panels) You can sort according to the "open source" column on the chart.

Answer (score 2):

There's [Ravencore](http://www.ravencore.com/) and [GPLHost](http://www.gplhost.com/software-dtc.html) and probably many more, those were just the first two google results for the pretty straightforward search string 'open source hosting control panel'.

Answer (score 1):

Kloxo is the best open source control panel

Comment: Can you be a bit more objective with your answer here perhaps?